# Unable to recognize master/representor on the multiple IB devices

Tags: dpdk, mellanox

I am getting DPDK MLX5 probing issue.

1. I have installed the mlx5/ofed driver
2. I have loaded the kernel modules.

```
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-2048kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1013) device: 0000:5e:00.0 (socket 0)
mlx5_pci: unable to recognize master/representors on the multiple IB devices
common_mlx5: Failed to load driver = mlx5_pci.

EAL: Requested device 0000:5e:00.0 cannot be used
EAL: Bus (pci) probe failed.
```

As for the 'failing to load mlx5_pci' driver, I can see that
the mlx5_core driver is loaded.

```
dpdk-devbind.py -s

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:5e:00.0 'MT27700 Family [ConnectX-4]' if=enp94s0 drv=mlx5_core unused=
```

I am assuming both of them are same?
What does failing to recognize master/representors on multiple IB devices mean?

My configuration is: CentOS 7.9, Linux Kernel 5.12, OFED 4.9 (LTS), DPDK 21.02

```
lsmod | egrep 'mlx|ib'

libceph               413696  1 ceph
ib_isert               49152  0
iscsi_target_mod      315392  1 ib_isert
ib_srpt                61440  0
target_core_mod       372736  3 iscsi_target_mod,ib_srpt,ib_isert
ib_srp                 61440  0
scsi_transport_srp     28672  1 ib_srp
ib_iser                45056  0
ib_umad                36864  0
rdma_cm               114688  6 rpcrdma,ib_srpt,ib_srp,ib_iser,ib_isert,rdma_ucm
ib_ipoib              114688  0
libiscsi               65536  1 ib_iser
scsi_transport_iscsi   126976  2 ib_iser,libiscsi
ib_cm                 122880  4 rdma_cm,ib_ipoib,ib_srpt,ib_srp
mlx5_ib               331776  0
mlx4_ib               196608  0
ib_uverbs             147456  3 mlx4_ib,rdma_ucm,mlx5_ib
ib_core               356352  14 rdma_cm,ib_ipoib,rpcrdma,mlx4_ib,ib_srpt,ib_srp,iw_cm,ib_iser,ib_umad,ib_isert,rdma_ucm,ib_uverbs,ml
5_ib,ib_cm
libcrc32c              16384  5 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_tables,xfs,libceph
mlx4_en               118784  0
mlx4_core             319488  2 mlx4_ib,mlx4_en
mlx5_core             700416  1 mlx5_ib
mlxfw                  32768  1 mlx5_core
pci_hyperv_intf        16384  1 mlx5_core
ptp                    28672  3 igb,mlx4_en,mlx5_core
libahci                36864  1 ahci
libata                253952  2 libahci,ahci
```

Comment: Please add details for 1. DPDK version, 2. result for lsmod | egrep 'mlx|ib', 3. restart mellanox idb service etc/init.d/openibd restart and retest again

Comment: @SankalpaTilsina is there an update?

Comment: @VipinVarghese Also the testpmd for the same interface is throwing: 
EAL:   probe driver: 15b3:1013 net_mlx5
net_mlx5: flow rules relying on switch offloads will not be supported: cannot retrieve network interface index: No such device or address

Comment: thanks for sharing the information, One thing which is not correct for me is `DPDK is reporting Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci` and `lspci is reporting `MT27700 Family [ConnectX-4]`. Something is definitely not right

Comment: are you sure your device is mlx5, as per lspci it is mlx4. can you cross check

Comment: Yes the interface is as shown in the lspci. The DPDK is trying to use that mlx4 interface. I am not sure why it loads mlx5_pci driver for mlx4 interfaces. Probably mlx5_pci supports mlx4 interfaces as well?

Comment: I do not know, I think this is an error, can you check with mxl team?

Comment: I have one suggestion please try `meson -D disable_drivers=net/mlx5 build ; ninja -C build`. Now you should get a result `net: af_packet, ark, atlantic, avp, axgbe, bond, bnx2x, bnxt,cxgbe, dpaa, dpaa2, e1000, ena, enetc, enic, failsafe,fm10k, i40e, hinic, hns3, iavf, ice, igc, ionic,ixgbe, kni, liquidio, memif, mlx4, netvsc, nfp, null,octeontx, octeontx2, octeontx_ep, pcap, pfe, qede, ring, sfc,softnic, tap, thunderx, txgbe, vdev_netvsc, vhost, virtio, vmxnet3,`

Comment: @SnkalpaTimilsina can you please share your update as suggested above?

Comment: I will. Currently there is some server related issues.

In the meantime, I would like to share that I have some alias interfaces for the interface that I am trying to use. Could that create a problem? I was expecting to check it, but I'm stuck due to few issues.

Comment: are there any updates on the same?